# Pass env vars from init container to main container

Tags: kubernetes, containers, init

I have an init container that gets key vault secrets and mounts it to a path available to the main container. How do I retrieve these secrets in main container as env vars?

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail. add some code where you think you are getting error. thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO; please refer to the following guide that might help you get an answer for your coding problem: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

initContainers complete before the other container(s) are started.  Ergo, you can assume your mount succeeded (because if it did not, the pod would be restarted), and can source the file as if it were always in the container to add it to the environment settings.